App trace with Perfetto not clear , to acclerate app startup
I have android app , java. It has viewpager with 6 pages. each page has subFragments, managed by viewpager. App was loading on Lenovo phone in 6 sec. but on Samsung phones (A14) in 80 seconds. I have loaded fragments with AsyncLayoutInflator. now app is loading in 18 seconds, but looks freezed, ie user cannot interact. then it waits for another 57 seconds till user can interact with it.
I have attached app trace into below link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RFCGnFGSSsIMmvc3rv5wyKItQvy2lATZ/view?usp=sharing
I have checked in Perfetto , but not clear for me. I have below sreenshot:

Question : trace in perfetto show 2 Choreographer#doFrame , first for 18 seconds ( which app needs to show views) , then second  Choreographer#doFrame , that has 57 seconds duration  >> which app is in freeze till user can interact.
How to know why it takes that long, in order to optimize my code.
NB. I noticed that in general samsung phones are quite slow for my app, while lenovo phones are faster, even if samsung phones have higher specs.
